# Iterate over a slice of items in a SortedDict?

Tags: python, sorteddictionary

I would like to iterate over a slice of *items* in a [sortedcontainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) SortedDict. I know that I can do something like this:

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedDict

d = SortedDict(b=20, d=30, c=10, e=50, a=40)

print [k, d[k] for k in in d.islice(1, 4)]
>> [('b', 20), ('c', 10), ('d', 30)]
```

but I'd like to avoid all of the individual `d[k]` lookups if possible; something like `d.iteritems()` that allows for a slice:

```
for k, v in d.islice_items(1, 4):
    print k, v
```

Is there any way to iterate over a slice of items in a SortedDict?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of v1.4.3 there isn't. The rationale is two fold:

1. Lookups are just so friggin [fast](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance.html#id3).
2. In the implementation, `SortedDict` inherits directly from `dict`. So the values themselves are stored in the `dict` and `SortedDict` has no way to get at them than to do the lookup itself.

If we added an `isliceitems` method it would do the same as you're doing.

You might try:

```
lookup = dict.__getitem__
print [k, lookup(d, k) for k in in d.islice(1, 4)]
```

But I would hope that's not faster.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I didn't try profiling the `itertools.islice` method I mentioned above. Worth doing?

Comment: It's always worth profiling. The `SortedDict` and start index probably have to be pretty large for it to matter (in the tens or hundreds of thousands).

Answer (score 0):

...and I figured out how to do it. Should have checked [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) before asking :/

```
import sortedcontainers
import itertools

d = sortedcontainers.SortedDict(b=20, d=30, c=10, e=50, a=40)

print [(k, d[k]) for k in d.islice(1, 4)]
# outputs: [('b', 20), ('c', 10), ('d', 30)]

print [i for i in itertools.islice(d.iteritems(), 1, 4)]
# outputs: [('b', 20), ('c', 10), ('d', 30)]
```

`itertools.islice` does the trick.

Comment: Don't do it this way. It's slower if the `SortedDict` and start index is large. `SortedDict.islice` has special means of slicing. `itertools.islice` just loops. See https://github.com/grantjenks/sorted_containers/blob/master/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.py#L787 for the source.